# System.out.println displays blank line

Tags: string, java-8, base64

Why does the below 'System.out.println'(fileEncodedString) display a blank line while the value is there when I debug and I do get an output when I decode the value and print.

```
byte[] fileContent = readFileToByteArray(filePath);
String fileEncodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);
byte[] fileDecodedString = Base64.getDecoder().decode(fileEncodedString);
System.out.println("Base64 Decoded File (Basic): " + new String(fileDecodedString, "utf-8"));

private static byte[] readFileToByteArray(String filePath) {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    byte[] bytesArray = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        // read file into bytes[]
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileInputStream.read(bytesArray);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fileInputStream != null) {
            try {
                fileInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    return bytesArray;
}
```

Comment: What is your `readFileToByteArray` method doing? If I have the following code to read a file your code works for me: `Path path = Paths.get("c:\\test.txt");
byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(path);`

Comment: Reading a file to a byteArray

Comment: I mean specifically what is it doing? What's the code? Your code works on my machine and the only difference is I can't see what you're doing in that method.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below method for readFileToByteArray and pass correct file path:

```
static byte[] readFileToByteArray(String filePath) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        return Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());

}
```

its working fine.

Comment: Nope! Still a blank line is been printed instead of the actual value in the console.